# Custom WebPart Layout Precompiled Web APP Staging Sync Error

Tags: kentico

We are running v8.2.48, and are having this error when trying to sync (via staging) a custom web part layout:

> SyncServer.ServerError: Exception occurred: Original code behind file
>   ('~/CMSWebParts/Membership/Logon/logonform.ascx.cs') for web part
>   PMCLogonForm does not exist.

A bit of background:

- .net 4
- Precompiled deployment on both dev and staging (source and target) and deployment mode on.
- Development in localhost with deployment mode on.

Is this error expected? Are we not meant to be able to sync web part layouts between precompiled sites with deployment mode on?

Comment: I'd try to turn off the deployment mode on target as suggested here: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Deployment+mode+for+virtual+objects there should be no reason to have it enabled on target anyway...

Comment: if I don't have it on on staging as well, I get the virtual path error... so I assumed that if you develop with deployment mode on, you should also have it on production.

Comment: @rocky as soon as I set deployment mode to off in staging, this happens: [Error loading the layout] 
The VirtualPathProvider is not running, you have to enable deployment mode in System -> Virtual objects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this isn't supported. See Documentation:

What can be synchronized - https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Content+staging#Contentstaging-Whatcanbesynchronized

**Content staging does not support synchronization of the following data:**

> Object code stored and edited in physical files via deployment mode or
>   source control mode

Comment: I'm not trying to sync the code nor the physical files, they are already there, as part of the compiled DLL and the Virtual Object file for the web part layout, all I'm trying to sync is the reference on the database for the webpart and the template using it to link the layout....